# error in android.toolchain.cmake for NDK maintained by opencv

Tags: opencv, android-ndk

I am using the android.toolchain.cmake to build specific libraries for a project. I have the latest NDK version -r8b and the latest cmake version -2.8.8. The error (line 611) - list index: 5 out of range (-4,3). If I check within the android.toolchain.cmake file it is at toolchaincompilerversion. Any input?

Answer (score 0):

Android NDK8b is not supported at the moment. Switch back NDK8 (to get that version, just remove the b from the download-link)